# Improving scalability when using Z3Py for passive learning

Tags: z3, theory, z3py

My team has been using the Z3 solver to perform passive learning. Passive learning entails obtaining from a set of observations a model consistent with all observations in the set. We consider models of different formalisms, the simplest being Deterministic Finite Automata (DFA) and Mealy machines. For DFAs, observations are just positive or negative samples.

The approach is very simplistic. Given the formalism and observations, we encode each observation into a Z3 constraint over (uninterpreted) functions which correspond to functions in the formalism definition. For DFAs for example, this definition includes a transition function (*trans: States X Inputs -> States*) and an output function (*out: States -> Boolean*).

Encoding say the observation (aa, +) would be done as follows:

*out(trans(trans(start,a),a)) ==  True*

Where *start* is the initial state. To construct a model, we add all the observation constraints to the solver. We also add a constraint which limits the number of states in the model. We solve the constraints for a limit of 1, 2, 3... states until the solver can find a solution. The solution is a minimum state-model that is consistent with the observations.

I posted a [code snippet using Z3Py](https://gist.github.com/pfg666/f405b128242df99e69f1d3a215d247b5) which does just this. Predictably, our approach is not scalable (the problem is NP-complete). I was wondering if there were any (small) tweaks we could perform to improve scalability? (in the way of trying out different sorts, strategies...)

We have already tried arranging all observations into a Prefix Tree and using this tree in encoding, but scalability was only marginally improved. I am well aware that there are much more scalable SAT-based approaches to this problem (reducing it to a graph coloring problem). We would like to see how far a simple SMT-based approach can take us.

So far, what I have found is that the best Sorts for defining inputs and states are *DeclareSort*. It also helps if we eliminate quantifiers from the state-size constraint. Interestingly enough, incremental solving did not really help. But it could be that I am not using it properly (I am an utter novice in SMT theory).

Thanks! BTW, I am unsure how viable/useful this test is as a benchmark for SMT solvers.